# unit testing modular javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, testing, javascript-framework

I am currently deriving a javascript framework pattern as an architecture for the client side development for an upcoming large scale application that I will developing.

I am looking to go with a module observer pattern in which each control I develop will have its own javascript file, holding no knoweldge of the other controls.

From designing this framework for my application, I am looking to integrate in a testing mechanism for my modules - a unit testing mechanism for javascript. I am not aware of any such frameworks or how I may set up such. Any suggestions?

As part of such testing, I will also need to mock up http requests.

The library I will be using in development is jquery.

Answer (score 7):

The JQuery team has [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit).

As for abstracting out AJAX, you should wrap it appropriately or just test the data manipulation methods.

Comment: I second Qunit. I would also recommend something like sinon.js or jasmine to mock/stub the ajax portion.

Answer (score 1):

[Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) may be what you are looking for. It has built-in mock up support, and does not rely on any other frameworks.

They also have a separate [module](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax) for faking AJAX responses.

The setup is simple. Just download the standalone version, write some testing suites, and view the SpecRunner.html in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [JsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) to run your JS tests. The main benefit it provides - it can run your tests on continuous integration environment, which is essential for unit testing practice.

Some additional features:

1. It can be used along with [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit) and other testing frameworks.
2. It can execute your tests in parallel across multiple browser.
3. It supports calculation code coverage.

List of mocking libraries you can find in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209418/what-are-some-javascript-unit-testing-and-mocking-frameworks-you-have-used).

Answer (score 0):

[BoilerplateJS](http://boilerplatejs.org)
is a reference architecture for large scale JavaScript product development. You can find the tests which are written using qunit, sinon and testr included under the  [tests folder.](https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs/tree/master/tests)